# C++ Struct implicit conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, implicit-conversion

I need to declare a good number of simple POD structures that will behave the same but that are really different types, i.e not typedefs.

Anyway I just want to keep them as simple as possible. But while testing I saw that the compiler performs some implicit conversions and I'd like to avoid this.

Given this code :

```
  template<typename T>
  struct Struct {
    T data;

    operator T() const { return data; }
  };

  void fun(Struct<float> value)
  {
    cout << "Call with Struct :: " << value << endl;
  }

  void fun(int value)
  {
    cout << "Call with INT :: " << value << endl;
  }

int main(int, char**)
{
  fun(3);
  fun(4.1f);
  fun(Struct<float>{5.2});
  fun(Struct<double>{6.3});
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with GCC.

The execution gives me  :

```
Call with INT :: 3       // Ok
Call with INT :: 4       // [1]
Call with Struct :: 5.2  // Ok
Call with INT :: 6       // [2]
```

How can I avoid implicit conversions [1] and [2] ?

Thanks

Comment: So you want it to only call the `int` overload if you give exactly an `int`?

Comment: @sftrabbit Yes and no. The most important is [2], and what I want is to forbidd Struct -> int conversion.

Comment: Well, correct me if I'm wrong, but there's still the `explicit` keyword.

Comment: you can use something like this `operator int() =delete;`

Comment: And what do you want as a result, instead? A compiler error?

Comment: @JBL explicit was for constructors in my mind. But this is perfect for my need.. You can post it as answer if you want :)
@ Koushik Yes I tried this, however this only restrict to int, I don't want to add an operator = delete for every possible type
@ jrok yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As requested in the comment :

The use of the explicit keyword for `operator T()` will actually prevent implicit type conversion.

Thus, declaring the struct this way:

```
template<typename T>
struct Struct {
    T data;

    explicit operator T() const { return data; }
};
```

will make the compiler prevent implicit conversion, and require that the client code specifically ask for a conversion (i.e. use `T(Struct<T>)` anywhere a T is required )